# How to run Tmux when opening a terminal in ArcoLinux?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I already know there are other questions like this, but their answers don't help me. I want to run Tmux when I open the terminal in ArcoLinux, that is based on Arch Linux, so in order to do this, I set the following line in my `.zshrc` config file.

```
tmux
```

but it shows an error when I open a terminal:

```
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:6: command not found: append_path
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:8: command not found: append_path
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:10: command not found: append_path
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.zshrc` file has nothing to do with this and you shouldn't be touching it at all for this.

Most (X11) terminal emulators have the idea of one or more "profiles" controlling how they behave.
Included in a "profile" is which command to run in each new terminal session.
This will usually default to the value of whatever `SHELL` environment variable the terminal emulator process has inherited, but can be explicitly set to a particular named program.

Set this to `tmux`, as the people at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197094/5132 and [Bash script to start tmux and issue commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332213/5132) did.